# Getting polygon shapefile node coordinates and point order

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point, coordinates, order

I am trying to get the coordinates of each node of a polygon in QGIS. What I basically did is use the following tools:

Vector -> Geometry tools -> Extract nodes

Vector -> Geometry tools -> Export Geometry column

However only around the first 300 points had successfully obtained coordinate values in the new xcoord and ycoord fields. The other three thousand plus points had null values. What can I do to get the other points' coordinates? Also is there an easy way to get the point order of each node?

Comment: have you tried adding the columns manually by using the `$x` and `$y` command in the field calculator (attributetable)?

Answer (score 2):

The `mmqgis` plugin also allows exporting geometry data to csv. The point order will be preserved.

On importing, the plugin does not like multipolygons.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed:

First: Need to Extract the NODES and save to a file
Second: Add the saved file (do not use tue file automaticaly generated into your project - in mine it doesnt work)
Third: Save the SHP of the Nodes added as an CSV file.

This way it works for me.

Thank you.